# Illegal expression in a pascal program

Tags: pascal

My code below throws an exception. Why?

```
program Masquerade(input, output);
    Begin 
 var amount, count, money : integer;
 writeln ('Welcome to the Wonder True Masquerade Band');
 writeln ('Would you like to proceed? Yes/No');

 var choice : String;
 readln (choice);
End.
```

Throws the error: `fatal: syntax error ";" expected but "identifier AMOUNT" found`

Where should the semi-colon go?

Answer (score 5):

Put `begin` after `var`.

I haven't used Pascal for years and don't have any compiler to test it, but it should be like this:

```
program Masquerade(input, output);
var
  amount, count, money : integer;
begin 
  writeln ('Welcome to the Wonder True Masquerade Band');
...
```

Comment: Exactly. You cannot declare variables inside code-blocks in pascal.